# What is the sum of the following equation?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

Let $\lambda_1>\lambda_2\cdots>\lambda_m>0$ be a decreasing sequence. Now, consider the following equation:
$$\sum_{j=1}^m\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{k\neq j}(1-\frac{\lambda_k}{\lambda_j})}$$
I have verified that the result of the above equation is $1$ when $m=2,3$.

I want to know how to get a general proof that the above conclusion holds for any positive integer $m$.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Consider the [Lagrange interpolating polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Although they both have $\prod\limits_{k\neq j}\lambda_j-\lambda_k$ in the denominator, they have a distinct difference in the numerator. Sorry, I still don't get your idea. Could you provide the concrete details?

Comment: Hi! A cousin formulation would be in terms of divided differences as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences)

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot!